# How to return the related field name when outputting serialized data in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a model that has two foreign keys to a user and an event. When I save a message I send in a user_id and an event_id but when an api call is made I want to return the user_name and the event_name not their ids.

```
class Message(models.Model):

class Meta:
    db_table = 'messages'

event = models.ForeignKey(Event, verbose_name="event", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="message user")
body = models.TextField(verbose_name='message')
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

As of now I have two different serializers the first one I use to save validate and save messages and the other I use to get the related field names but it seems really redundant.

```
class GetMessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    event = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ('user', 'event', 'body')


class SaveMessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ('user', 'event', 'body')
```

Is there a way I can have one message serializer that accepts and saves a request that has user and event ids but returns the associated names of the model?

This is the associated views if it helps:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def messages(request, event_id):
    JSON_RESPONSE = {STATUS: None, DATA: None, MESSAGE: None}
    messages = Message.objects.filter(event=event_id)
    serializer = GetMessageSerializer(messages, many=True)
    JSON_RESPONSE[STATUS] = SUCCESS
    JSON_RESPONSE[DATA] = serializer.data
    return Response(JSON_RESPONSE, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

@api_view(['POST'])
def saveMessage(request):
    JSON_RESPONSE = {STATUS: None, DATA: None, MESSAGE: None}
    serializer = SaveMessageSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        JSON_RESPONSE[STATUS] = SUCCESS
        JSON_RESPONSE[MESSAGE] = "Saved" 
        serializer.save()
        return Response(JSON_RESPONSE, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        JSON_RESPONSE[STATUS] = FAIL
        JSON_RESPONSE[MESSAGE] = serializer.errors
```

Comment: by returning names of model you want to return 'event' as a string or name field on event model?

Comment: you can have a whole object of the user and event and you can easily get the names from the object list. so you will not have to create different serializers for save and get purpose.